# select count () how to add column

Tags: sql, firebird

This request gives me the count of the request occurrences where EMAIL occures.

```
    select count(*) 
    from ADRESS K left outer join ADRESS L 
       on K.LFDNRSECONDADRESS=L.LFDNR 
    left outer join ADRESS V 
       on K.VERLFDNR=V.LFDNR 
    where ((UPPER(K.EMAIL)= 'my@email.com' 
       or exists (select ADRESSEMAILADR.LFDNR 
                  from ADRESSEMAILADR 
                  where ADRESSEMAILADR.ADRESSLFDNR=K.LFDNR 
                     and UPPER(ADRESSEMAILADR.EMAIL)= 
                                'my@email.com' )
    )) and K.ART='K'
```

But I also would like go get all occurrences of the column "LFDNR".

Like

```
3 
1234 
2345 
3456
...
```

So the first is the count and the followingup are the results of all columns where LFDNR = X.

Of cause I tried

```
LFDNR, select count(*)  
K.LFDNR, select count(*)
```

And so on...
No luck so far.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want `group by`:

```
select k.LFDNR, count(*) 
from ADRESS K left outer join
     ADRESS L 
     on K.LFDNRSECONDADRESS = L.LFDNR left outer join
     ADRESS V 
    on K.VERLFDNR = V.LFDNR 
 where (UPPER(K.EMAIL)= 'my@email.com' or
        exists (select ADRESSEMAILADR.LFDNR 
                from ADRESSEMAILADR 
                where ADRESSEMAILADR.ADRESSLFDNR = K.LFDNR and
                      UPPER(ADRESSEMAILADR.EMAIL) = 'my@email.com'
               )
       ) and
       K.ART = 'K'
 group by k.LFDNR;
```

Comment: It gave me an error untill I used: select 
  COUNT(*) as FIELD_1,
  K.LFDNR

Comment: @MichaelMüller . . . Yes, I see that the join is on the same table, so a table alias is needed.